# script apenas em uma div

Tags: javascript, html

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    onmousemove = function adfy() {
        adfy_id = '.html'; //replace with your ID
        for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
            var hrefer = document.links[i].href;
            if (hrefer.match(".html") || hrefer.match("javascript:") || hrefer.match("#")) {
                document.links[i].href = document.links[i].href;
            } else {
                document.links[i].href = document.links[i].href + adfy_id;
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

```html
<a href="test.html">com .html</a>
<a href="test">sem .html</a>
```

to usando esse codido do adfly pra por .html nos links do meu site, são mais de 300 então não to afim de fazer manualmente.
Funcionou muito bem, porem ele esta atrapalhando outros links que não precisam dele.

Queria saber se tem como fazer funcionar apenas em uma div?

Comment: Não estou com tempo para responder agora, mas 1 pergunta: a tua página tem conteúdo dinamico ou o HTML é o mesmo desde que a página carrega. `adfy_id` é declarado algures?

Comment: HTML, não apenas na função

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione um atributo de `'id'` (com um nome, claro) para sua `div` e use o método `document.getElementById` para capturar ela. Portanto, você não terá a propriedade `links` no seu elemento e terá que usar `HTMLElement.prototype.getElementsByTagName` para pegar os hyperlinks da `div` em uma array.

Se possível, poderia explicar o porquê de usar o evento `onmousemove` para atualizar os hyperlinks? Isso pode causar lentidões...

```js
window['onmousemove'] = (function adfy() {

    /* Href file extension */
    var fileFormat = '.html';

    var div = document.getElementById("id"),
        links = div.getElementsByTagName("a");

    /* Iterate through the links */
    for (var i = 0, a; a = links[i]; i++) {
        if (a['href'].match(".html") || a['href'].match("javascript:") || a['href'].match("#")) {
            a.href = a['href'];
        } else a.href = a['href'] + fileFormat;
    }

});
```

```html
<div id="id">
  <a href="test.html">com .html</a>
  <a href="test">sem .html</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adicione aos links que quer que tenha `.html` uma class, neste caso adicionei `.addHtml`. Assim a function só irá funcionar nesses elementos.

```
<a href="test.html" class="addHtml">com .html</a>
<a href="test">sem .html</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    onmousemove = function adfy() {
        adfy_id = '.html'; //replace with your ID
        links = document.getElementsByClassName("addHtml");
        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            var hrefer = links[i].href;
            if (hrefer.match(".html") || hrefer.match("javascript:") || hrefer.match("#")) {
                links[i].href = links[i].href;
            } else {
                links[i].href = links[i].href + adfy_id;
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```